# How to set Vue Core UI select value

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, core-ui

Sorry for the beginner question, I am new to Vue.js. I am using [CoreUI](https://coreui.io/vue/docs/introduction/). Documentation/Tutorials on CoreUI+Vue are scarce.

I am using the `<CForm>` tag and here I have a `<CSelect>` tag.

```html
<CForm @submit="test" ref="form">
  <CSelect
    label="Pick a name"
    :options="['test', 'test1', 'test2']"
    v-model="testy"
  />
  
  <CButton type="submit" size="sm" color="primary"> Submit</CButton>
</CForm>
```

JavaScript:

```js
methods: {
  test(e) {
    console.log("test");
    debugger;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

When my breakpoint is hit and I inspect `this.testy` it will not return the value of the select box but instead this:

[image]

I was under the impression that putting `v-model` on my `CSelect` will expose my select box under `this.*` and I could somehow easily get the value (?!).

For context this is rendered in the DOM:

```html
<select id="uid-wvkj98yh6gp" class="form-control">
  <option data-key="0" value="test"> test </option>
  <option data-key="1" value="test1"> test1 </option>
  <option data-key="2" value="test2"> test2 </option>
</select>
```

My question: inside my `test(e)` method, how can I gather the current selected value of my select box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `<CSelect>` API [docs](https://coreui.io/vue/docs/components/form-components.html#cselect-api), it lists the `value` prop:

> value
>
> The value of select input. Set `.sync` modifier to track prop changes.

It seems they don't use `v-model` as expected and you probably also got an error about the `value` prop being incorrect.

Change your select to:

```html
<CSelect
  label="Pick a name"
  :options="['test', 'test1', 'test2']"
  :value.sync="testy"
/>
```

This way you use the [`.sync`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) modifier the way the guide directs.

Comment: Awesome, that did work. As a total noob with VueJS it wasn't a good idea to jump straight into CoreUI, because I don't know which behaviour is VueJS and which is CoreUI related - and also the CoreUI docs are quite alien to me. Thanks though..!

Comment: You're welcome.  Yeah it seems they do things a little differently.  You won't find many libraries opting for `.sync` over `v-model` like this.